# How to change time format generated from time.toLocaleString()

Tags: javascript

The time format that I get now with the below code is `8:33 PM` but I am trying to figure out how to do like this:

`8:33pm` lower case and without space.

```js
var time = new Date();
console.log(
  time.toLocaleString('en-US', { hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric', hour12: true })
);
```

There is alway hard way to accomplish this task like I did below, but I am wondering is there any easy way so that I can configure `time.toLocaleString()` and that does the magic :) Just Vanilla JS without help of any plugins.

```js
var time = new Date();
var toLocale = time.toLocaleString('en-US', { hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric', hour12: true })
console.log(toLocale.replace(' ', '').toLowerCase());
```

Comment: seems not to be possible with only using `toLocaleString()` https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you can't change the return format of functions which are native to javascript, (perhaps with monkey patching but that causes a lot of other problems). And according to https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString this is also not implemented in `toLocaleString()` method.

I recommend doing all time and date manipulations in js with https://momentjs.com/ it is a super helpful and easy to use library and requires a lot less typing than the native library :)

If you use moment you would only need to write

```
moment().format('h:mma')
```

Which would give you the desired format you are looking for. To add moment to your js either use it inline like

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/2.14.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```

or better yet add it to your project with npm or yarn and import it :)

Comment: this is not an answer to the question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: @messerbill the guidelines don't say anything about recommending a helpful library

Comment: `so that I can configure time.toLocaleString()`  but this is the question of the TO not how to achieve that output format in `any` way

Comment: TO already achieved this output format so recommending `moment.js` does not answer his question at all

Comment: You can't change the return output format of a native function. You can only manipulate the returned response with some code you wrote yourself or other code written particularly for this scenario.
I offered a solution which works to the question he asked "There is alway hard way to accomplish this task like I did below, but I am wondering is there any easy way "

Comment: yes this is true - but changes nothing to the question / answer. I don't want to blame you, this is just not the topic here. Edit your answer and explain the TO why this is not possible in the way he tried and if you want to keep your moment.js example keep it and i will upvote this

Comment: that's a fair point @messerbill , my original answer does make a lot of assumptions without explaining why they are in place :)

Comment: Guys, I was looking for just Vanilla JS without any plugins.